# Error: misconfigured csrf - Express.js

Tags: javascript, express, csrf

I'm getting `Error: misconfigured csrf` when I'm trying to access my login-page. I'm implementing the csurf to a router, but I'm just getting the response statuscode 500.

Implementation:

```
let router = require("express").Router();

let PostLoginResource = require("./../resources/PostLoginResource");
let RateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
let csrf = require("csurf");

let csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });

router.route("/login")
    .get(csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
        // Do some stuff
    })

    .post(loginLimiter, function(req, res) {

        PostLoginResource(req, function(success, err) {
            // Do some stuff
        })

    });
```

I'm starting the session-cookie before I'm using this module in app.js:

```
// Parse the request body as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Parse the URL encoded data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Set up session-cookie
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
}));
```

Still, this is not working. Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: is that path correct: ./../resources/PostLoginResource?

Comment: Yes, otherwise that would be the error-message, not Error: misconfigured csrf

Comment: well you did got a 500, meaning internal error. incorrect statements causes it.Where did you require the session object>

Answer (score 1):

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
```

parse cookies
  we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: note* The call to app.use(csrf()) must be set after app.use(cookieParser()) AND app.use(session({...}).

Comment: As official description of express session middleware: https://github.com/expressjs/session

'Since version 1.5.0, the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this module to work. This module now directly reads and writes cookies on req/res. Using cookie-parser may result in issues if the secret is not the same between this module and cookie-parser.'